# How to persist Twitter Authorizer ITwitterAuthorizer

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, windows-phone-8

How can i persist the Twitter authentication so that it doesn't need authentication every time i want to send tweet from my Windows phone 8 App
i am using LINQTOTWITTER sdk by using PinAuthorizer

code is below that executes after giving the Authentication code in 'PinTextBox.Text'
this PinAuthorizer is used to check whether authentication is done or not. i need to persist this object or use any mechanism so that user don't need to provide authentication code every time.

```
private void AuthenticateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pinAuth.CompleteAuthorize(
            PinTextBox.Text,
            completeResp => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                switch (completeResp.Status)
                {
                    case TwitterErrorStatus.Success:
                        AppSettings.TwitterAuthorizer = pinAuth;
                        NavigationService.GoBack();
                        break;
                    case TwitterErrorStatus.TwitterApiError:
                    case TwitterErrorStatus.RequestProcessingException:
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            completeResp.Error.ToString(),
                            completeResp.Message,
                            MessageBoxButton.OK);
                        break;
                }
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the access token you get from Twitter after the successful login in IsolatedStorage and use the same access token whenever you need to post a tweet.

You didnot mention which Twitter SDK you are using in your App. It depends on the SDK you use. If my answer doesn't solve your problem, update your question with more data.

I have never worked on LINQTOTWITTER. Here is a discussion about the similar problem. I hope the solution mentioned there solves it.

[Getting Access Token after Pin Auth has completed](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/267154)

Comment: pinAuth.CompleteAuthorize(
                PinTextBox.Text,
                completeResp => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    switch (completeResp.Status)
                    {
                        case TwitterErrorStatus.Success:
                            AppSettings.TwitterAuthorizer = pinAuth;

Comment: i have updated the question description, please read again and suggest me.